# Is JS function executed when JS writes innerHTML with said function?

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code that changes the innerHTML of a `div`. This innerHTML contains the call of a JS function. The definition of the function is also contained the in the same .js file. Will the JS function `validate_login_password` be executed after the changed innerHTML is done?

```
function startup(mode) {
  return function () {
    if (mode == "login") {
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = `                                                                                                                               
<div class="grid-auth">                                                                                                                                                           
<div class="item3">                                                                                                                                                               
<form action="/login.pl">                                                                                                                                                         
<label for="username">Nome de usuário</label>                                                                                                                                     
<input type="text" id="login_username" name="login_username" required>                                                                                                            
<label for="login_password">Senha</label>                                                                                                                                         
<input type="password" id="login_password" name="login_password" required>                                                                                                        
<input type="submit" value="Iniciar sessão">                                                                                                                                      
</form>                                                                                                                                                                           
</div>                                                                                                                                                                            
<div class="item4">                                                                                                                                                               
<form action="/login.pl">                                                                                                                                                         
<label for="username">Nome completo</label>                                                                                                                                       
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>                                                                                                                                
<label for="username">Nome de usuário</label>                                                                                                                                     
<input type="text" id="signup_username" name="signup_username" required>                                                                                                          
<label for="email">Email</label>                                                                                                                                                  
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>                                                                                                                             
<label for="signup_password">Senha</label>                                                                                                                                        
<input type="password" id="signup_password" name="signup_password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}.{?=.*[!@#$%^&.?]" title="Deve conter pelo menos um número, uma le\
tra maiúscula, uma letra minúscila, um dos símbolos !?@#$%^&. e pelo menos 8 caracteres" required>                                                                                
<input type="submit" value="Criar conta">                                                                                                                                         
</form>                                                                                                                                                                           
</div>                                                                                                                                                                            
<div class="item5" id="message">                                                                                                                                                  
<h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>                                                                                                                                     
<p id="letter" class="invalid">Uma letra <b>minúscula</b></p>                                                                                                                     
<p id="capital" class="invalid">Uma letra <b>maiúscula</b></p>                                                                                                                    
<p id="number" class="invalid">Um <b>número</b></p>                                                                                                                               
<p id="symbol" class="invalid">Um <b>símbolo</b></p>                                                                                                                              
<p id="length" class="invalid">Mínimo <b>8 caracteres</b></p>                                                                                                                     
</div>                                                                                                                                                                            
</div>                                                                                                                                                                            
<script>validate_signup_password()</script>`;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "<h1>Olá mundo</h1>";
    }
  }
}

function validate_signup_password () {
 ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: i don't think so.

Comment: innerHTML does not evaluate script tags.

Comment: No. Only scripts injected into the head element will run after initial page load. Inject your content where it needs to be.

Comment: You don't really need that anyway.  After assigning the `innerHTML`, just do `validate_signup_password();`.

Comment: I tried placing the code in the `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` and it seems that the writing of the innerHTML stops when the </script> closing tag inside innerHTML is hit. It seems that it should've waited for the </script> closing tag outside of the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood the question but wouldn't it be better to add an event listener to the innerHTML change event?  I think this can be done now, see: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe)

Answer (score -2):

Yes... Your function will be executed after creating new innerHtml..
Even you don't need to give script tag inside your innerHtml.
You can just declare function name and use your function directly.
As javascript functions can be called directly from a single file.

```
function startup(mode) {
if (mode == "login") {
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = `                                                                                                                               
  <div class="grid-auth">                                                                                                                                                           
  <div class="item3">                                                                                                                                                               
  <form action="/login.pl">                                                                                                                                                         
  <label for="username">Nome de usuário</label>                                                                                                                                     
  <input type="text" id="login_username" name="login_username" required>                                                                                                            
  <label for="login_password">Senha</label>                                                                                                                                         
  <input type="password" id="login_password" name="login_password" required>                                                                                                        
  <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sessão">                                                                                                                                      
  </form>                                                                                                                                                                           
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <div class="item4">                                                                                                                                                               
  <form action="/login.pl">                                                                                                                                                         
  <label for="username">Nome completo</label>                                                                                                                                       
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>                                                                                                                                
  <label for="username">Nome de usuário</label>                                                                                                                                     
  <input type="text" id="signup_username" name="signup_username" required>                                                                                                          
  <label for="email">Email</label>                                                                                                                                                  
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>                                                                                                                             
  <label for="signup_password">Senha</label>                                                                                                                                        
  <input type="password" id="signup_password" name="signup_password" pattern="(? 
   =.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}.{?=.*[!@#$%^&.?]" title="Deve conter pelo 
  menos um número, uma le\
  tra maiúscula, uma letra minúscila, um dos símbolos !?@#$%^&. e pelo menos 8 
  caracteres" required>                                                                                
  <input type="button" value="Criar conta" 
   onclick="validate_signup_password()">                                                                                                                                         
  </form>                                                                                                                                                                           
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                            
  <div class="item5" id="message">                                                                                                                                                  
  <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>                                                                                                                                     
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">Uma letra <b>minúscula</b></p>                                                                                                                     
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">Uma letra <b>maiúscula</b></p>                                                                                                                    
  <p id="number" class="invalid">Um <b>número</b></p>                                                                                                                               
  <p id="symbol" class="invalid">Um <b>símbolo</b></p>                                                                                                                              
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Mínimo <b>8 caracteres</b></p>                                                                                                                     
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                            
  </div>`;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "<h1>Olá mundo</h1>";
      }

  }

  function validate_signup_password () {
   "Your Code/Logic"
  }
```

[ADDING CODEPEN TO CHECK](https://codepen.io/Dhruvil-Mehta/pen/PoxgaXq)

Comment: `Yes...` you meant of course `No... you have to write different code`

Comment: No...No need to write different code if he wants to execute his innerHtml code and call JS function he can...

Comment: well, how come you removed `<script>validate_signup_password()</script>` from the original code? and how will `validate_signup_password()` ever be called?

Comment: Assumed that he is already writing the code on script tag and when rendered the innerHtml ,the scripts will already been called and inside on click or wherever function needs to be used will be called directly from the scripts itself

Comment: @Jaromanda X I tried removing the <script>validate_signup_password()</scrip> and it doesn't work. I tried substituting for just validate_signup_password() and also doesn't work.  Could you please give an example of how I should write my code? Thanks!

Comment: call your function just above `} else {` in the so-called answer

Comment: @MarcosCamargo I Have added codepen link as well... You can check the same

Comment: @DhruvilMehta I checked your CODEPEN example. It doesn't execute the function validate_signup_password.

Comment: @MarcosCamargo I have simply added "onClick" alert of "Cirar Conta" button...
So when you fill your form and click the button then your function will be called...
Of Course you can always change the property according to your requirement.!